# SpringWebMVC - - Buscar Data com @ModelAtribute

Tags: spring-mvc

Olá, tenho o seguinte método:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/pesquisa", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String pesquisa(@ModelAttribute("relSintetico") @Valid RelSintetico relSintetico, BindingResult bindingResult) {

    Timestamp dataInicial =  relSintetico.getDataInicial();

    Timestamp dataFinal = relSintetico.getDataFinal();

    System.out.println("Pesquisando");
    System.out.println(dataInicial);


    List<VE_RelResumoArrecadacao> relatorio = repositorioSintetico.findByDataOperacao(dataInicial, dataFinal);

    System.out.println("Pesquisado!");
    System.out.println(relatorio.size());


    return "sintetico.relatorios.tiles";
}
```

Tal método pega o "modelAtribute" relSintetico da página abaixo:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

### Relatório Sintético

Essa é a classe Modelo de RelSintetico:

```
package br.com.apasi.spring.dominios;
```

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "RelSintetico", catalog = "Pedagio", schema = "dbo")
public class RelSintetico implements Serializable {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name = "IdRelSintetico")
private Integer idRelSintetico;

@Column(name = "DataInicial")
private Timestamp dataInicial;

@Column(name = "DataFinal")
private Timestamp dataFinal;

public Integer getIdRelSintetico() {
    return idRelSintetico;
}

public void setIdRelSintetico(Integer idRelSintetico) {
    this.idRelSintetico = idRelSintetico;
}

public Timestamp getDataInicial() {
    return dataInicial;
}

public Timestamp getDataFinal() {
    return dataFinal;
}

public void setDataInicial(Timestamp dataInicial) {
    this.dataInicial = dataInicial;
}

public void setDataFinal(Timestamp dataFinal) {
    this.dataFinal = dataFinal;
}
```

}

Mas o método retorna null para getDataInicial e getDataFinal...
Tem algo haver com conversão de data? ou estou pegando de maneira errada esses dados do Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca a anotação `@org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat` nos atributos de data informando o formato, acrescentando `javax.persistence.Temporal` e trocando o tipo de timestamp para java.util.Date conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "DataInicial")
private Date dataInicial;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "DataFinal")
private Date dataFinal;
```

Comment: Ainda Retorna null nas variáveis :(

Comment: Posta o JSP onde está o formulário... No meu projeto está mapeado como java.util.Date, pode ser isso também... Reeditei a resposta, veja se funciona agora...

Comment: <c:url var="actionPesquisar" value="/relatorios/pesquisa"></c:url>
<div>
 <form:form action="${actionPesquisar}"  modelAttribute="relSintetico" method="post"> 
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
     <form:input  path="dataInicial" type="date" cssClass="form-control" />
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
     <form:input path="dataFinal" type="date" cssClass="form-control" />

Comment: Mudei para Date e ainda vem como null

Comment: Tenta colocar o objeto no ModelAndView antes de carregar a página, tipo: ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("viewName"); modelAndView.addObject("relSintetico", new RelSintetico()); no mais não vejo porque não está funcionando...

Comment: essa tag type="date" não existe em <form:input> To tentando resolver esse problema.

Comment: Deus certo amigão... Não volta mais com valor Null, oque vc disse tava certo, o problema é que eu não apaguei o get e set com Timestamp kkkk valew